# Async function inside useMemo not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I have a situation in which I have an object with all the books and I want to get the author info which sits in a different collection. I tried fetching the data inside a useMemo, but I get an error since the promise does not get resolved I guess. How to make useMemo wait for the data to come for the author?

```
async function useAuthor(authorID:string) { 
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(authorID).get().then(doc => {
         return doc.data();
    })   
};      

  const normalizedBooks = useMemo(
    () =>
      books?.map( (book) => ({
        ...book,
        author: useAuthor(book.authorId),
      })),
    [books]
  );
```

Comment: Is `useAuthor` a custom React hook? Or is it really just an `async` utility function?

Comment: Just an async function

Comment: The `use*` naming convention is only intended to be used for actual hooks (functions that use at least one built-in-hook or are composed of custom hooks that do that). _"How to make useMemo wait for the data to come for the author?"_ You shouldn't do that in the first place. The way to fetch data is to initialise a state with no (or empty) data and fetch the required data in a `useEffect`. During fetching your component should either display a placeholder or a loading indicator or something of that kind. There should be nothing async blocking rendering of your components.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching remote data should be done in an effect:

```
function useAuthor(authorID:string) { 
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        firestore.collection('users').doc(authorID).get().then(
            doc => setAuthor(doc.data())
        );   
    }, [authorID]);

    return author;
}
```

Note that `author` will be `null` during the first render and until the request completed. You can improve that example by e.g. adding loading and error states. Or you can also use something like [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) which provides those out of the box:

```
import useQuery from 'react-query';

function getItemById(collectionID:string, itemID:string) {
    return firestore.collection(collectionID).doc(itemID).get().then(
        doc => doc.data()
    );
}

const Author = ({authorID}) => {
    const {data: author, isLoading, error} = useQuery(
        ['users', authorID], 
        getItemById
    );

    if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'

    if (error) return 'Failed to fetch author :(';

    return <p>{author.name}</p>;
}
```

Comment: When I use the function with useEffect in it it complains that it "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render"

Comment: @bobypoz That is because you shouldn't use it that way. It's simply not a good idea to try and fetch all the authors during your `.map()` call anyways. Depending on how you use the author later on you should better pass just the `authorID` to a component that does the fetching and displaying of the author. How did you get the books list in the first place and how do you use the authors?

Comment: That is what I did in the end.....I passed a state to a child component and fetched all of the data there which I returned via state to the parent.